# Why is my accuracy in a keras 3d CNN always 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm fairly new to keras, cnn and deep learning in general, so i'm super sorry, if the solution is quite simple. I'm really at a dead end here.

So - the thing is, I have a 3D CNN with cubes of 50x50x50 as input data. I want to classify them into either 0 or 1, so it is a binary classification problem. Before fitting it into the NN, I of course prepared the data, refactored, resized and normalized it. So the images are comparable (1 voxel is 2 mm), normalized to a 0 to 1 range and all the same size.

So, when i tried to fit the data into my model, the results are not that encouraging. The accuracy is always displayed as 0, with the highest accuracy i've had in a single epoch is `accuracy: 0.0159`, the loss always in between 3.2 and 3.5

I variated the number of epochs as well, but it does not matter if i have 5 or 50. the result is always the same.

This is the code of my CNN-architecture

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), activation='linear',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_shape=shape))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(Dropout(.25))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='linear',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
    model.add(Dropout(.25))

    model.add(Conv3D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='linear',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(Dropout(.25))
    model.add(Conv3D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='linear',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
    model.add(Dropout(.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(.1))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    print(training_patients[0])
    model.summary()
    model.fit(training_patients, training_labels, epochs=50, batch_size=50)
```

So I wanted to ask, if there is anything wrong with my architecture? Or do you think the problem is more on the data-side?

I have only 420 images; 3/4 of them I use for training, 1/4 is for testing. Could this be the problem?
I wanted to augment the images later on, when the base model is running stable. Or do I have to do this first?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you print out the shape of your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense for a classification problem with two classes:

```
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Change it to this:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Also consider using `'relu'` activation instead of `'linear'` for your convolution layers.

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you!

But I still don't quite understand what exactly the problem was and why it works now. Could you explain why it didn't make sense before? 

After all, I don't just want a working program, I want to learn something from my mistakes.

Comment: Well batch norm is a complex operation that simply doesn't make sense here. Also, the number of neurons on the output layer should almost always be the number of categories you have (except if you have two classes, you can put 1, and use binary_crossentropy and sigmoid activation).

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now!